# Why do both "std::printf" and "printf" compile when using <cstdio> rather than <stdio.h> in C++?

Tags: c++, namespaces, header-files

To my knowledge, headers of the form `cxyz` are identical to `xyz.h` with the only difference being that `cxyz` places all of the contents of `xyz.h` under the namespace `std`. Why is it that the following programs both compile on GCC 4.9 and clang 6.0?

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    printf("Testing...");
    return 0;
}
```

and the second program:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    std::printf("Testing...");
    return 0;
}
```

The same goes for the FILE struct:

```
FILE* test = fopen("test.txt", "w");
```

and

```
std::FILE* test = std::fopen("test.txt", "w");
```

both work.

Up until now, I always thought that it was better to use `cstdio`, `cstring`, etc, rather than their non-namespaced counterparts. However, which of the following two programs above are better practice?

The same goes for other C functions such as memset (from cstring), scanf (also from cstdio), etc.

(I know some people will ask why I am using C IO in a C++ program; the issue here is not specifically C IO, but whether or not this code should compile without specifically specifying `std::` before calling a namespaced C function.)

Comment: I see. So in my code, which style should I use if I wish to use, for example, memset from the cstring header? Is it better to write 'std::memset' or 'memset''

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard permits the compiler to also inject the names into the global namespace.

One reason for this is that it permits the implementation of `<cstdio>` to be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

namespace std
{
    using ::printf;
    using ::fopen;
    // etc.
}
```

so the compiler/library vendor does not have to write and maintain so much code.

In your own code, always use `std::` or `using namespace std;` etc. so that your code is portable to compilers which do not inject the names into global namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It was a little confusing since I haven't yet seen a compiler that doesn't inject the names into the global namespace.

Comment: @Ra1nMaster they probably do it to avoid bug reports / support issues from people who want to know why `printf` isn't working

Comment: @ra1nmaster: strictly speaking, it's the standard library and not the compiler which is responsible for injecting (or not) the functions into the global namespace.

Comment: @rici the existance of a standard library is an implementation detail for the compiler