# Error: std::fopen is not a member of std

Tags: c, arduino, fopen

I'm using Arduino IDE, and I'm trying to read from a text file using `fopen` function, but it does not work, it shows this error "`std::fopen` is not a member of `std`"

```
void tst() {
    FILE *fp = std::fopen("test.txt", "r");
    char str[60];

    if (fgets(str, 60, fp) == 0) {
        digitalWrite(pin, HIGH); 
    } else {
        digitalWrite(pin, LOW); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you remembered to `#include <cstdio>`, as opposed to just `<stdio.h>`?

Comment: @iharob `std::fopen` *is* a function. While the use of C++ streams is possible in C++, it is by no means mandatory, C-style IO is mandated by the C++ standard.

Comment: @user4815162342 Sorry, I didn't know that.

Comment: The OP is using Arduino's development language that is neither C nor C++ but closer to the first than the second.

Answer (score 4):

You have to include `cstdio` via `#include <cstdio>` in the file where `std::fopen` is supposed to be used.

Comment: In the Arduino environment, this is not true.

Answer (score 3):

If you use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

then you need to use `fopen`, without the `std` namespace.

If you use

```
#include <cstdio>
```

then you can use `std::fopen`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Eventually, I recognised that the Arduino IDE can not read a file from my PC, there is no other way to do that except from an SD card.

Thank you all

Answer (score -1):

Instead use this:

```
FILE* fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
```

Classes and namespaces are C++ features.  Not C.

Comment: The OP is likely using C++, or the error message would look very different. `std::fopen` [works in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28227006/1600898) as long as the appropriate header is included.

Comment: @user4815162342:  In the Arduino environment, programmers do not write any `#include`s.  The environment guesses which .H files to include automatically, but it is subject to many assumptions.  Even in `c++`, fopen() works just fine.

Comment: even after I included the library stdio.h, the compilers does not recognise the fopen

Comment: @AfnanHumdan:  Did you also remove the `std::` before `fopen()`?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. (The downvote is not from me.)